# Test that private method is not called when public method is called

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I have an authorizer#getToken method that returns a token. The first time it gets called, it authenticates by posting to an API; each call thereafter returns the token that was received from the API call. I need to test that the private method that hits the API does not get called (via `#authenticate`) when a token already exists. `#sessionIsValid` is the function that checks for an existing token. Here's my test:

```
        it('does not authenticate', async () => {
            authorizer['sessionIsValid'] = jest.fn(() => true);

            await authorizer.getToken();
            expect(authorizer['authenticate']).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

Jest is complaining with

```
    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

I've tried `jest.spyOn(authorizer, 'authenticate')` but get `Argument of type '"authenticate"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"getToken"'`.

I can't quite connect the dots here. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you test that the request doesn't get made, rather than that the private method doesn't get called? The point of private methods is that _they're private_, they're implementation details you should be entirely free to refactor around.

Comment: I already have a test for that - maybe that's good enough already.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct test to have.